# Arduino Leonardo keyboard behavior

Tags: keyboard, arduino

I want to use the Arduino Leonardo as a keyboard input with the inbuilt library.

```
boolean on;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);

  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);

  Keyboard.begin();
  on = true;
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    Keyboard.end();
    on = false;
  }
  digitalWrite(13, on);

  if(digitalRead(3) == LOW) {
    Keyboard.press('w');
  }
  else {
    Keyboard.release('w');
  }

}
```

Is it normal that the "Keyboard.press()" function still works after I ran "Keyboard.end()"?

I just don't want the Arduino to break.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the begin() function in:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);

  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);

  Keyboard.begin();
  on = true;
}
```

And you have ended the communication in

```
 if(digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    Keyboard.end();
    on = false;
  }
```

Once the digitalRead(2) value goes low, the communication protocol is stopped. You have to use another Keyboard.begin() before:

```
if(digitalRead(3) == LOW)
{
    Keyboard.press('w');
}
```

The best practice is to use `Keyboard.begin();` within `void loop()`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of what you're trying to do, you should do this:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
boolean on;
boolean disable;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);

  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);

  disable = false;
  on = true;
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    disable = true;
    on = false;
  }

  digitalWrite(13, on);

  if(disable == false) {
    if(digitalRead(3) == LOW) {
      Keyboard.press('w');
    }
    else {
      Keyboard.release('w');
    }
  }
}
```

That `#include` at the start I'm using is because I'm using the latest version of Arduino IDE.

Anyway, no matter if you are on your version or the latest version of Arduino IDE, `Keyboard.begin()` and `Keyboard.end()` do nothing, as I just tested it on my Arduino Leonardo-like board (I'm using Leostick instead of the genuine Arduino).

I'm not sure if I'm entirely right. It could depend on different operating systems (even though nothing went wrong when I tried both Windows and Mac). In all honesty, I'd leave them there just to be on the safe side, also to make your code easier to understand.

By the way, you won't break your Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard `begin` and `end` do not currently do anything and omitting them should not affect your code. If you go to the [Keyboard Library Github repo](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Keyboard/blob/master/src/Keyboard.cpp) and check the `begin` and `end` functions, you'll find them empty

```
void Keyboard_::begin(void)
{
}

void Keyboard_::end(void)
{
}
```